# Updating from Windows 8 to 8.1 keeps programs

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

Will updating windows 8 to 8.1 cause problem with my insalled programs like antivirus or firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the OS might pose problems with some old programs because they are not compatible with the current structure of OSs i suppose and AntiVirus programs due to some licensing and date change/OS Change issues.

Answer (score 0):

You probably keep every Program. But remember to make a backup of your files or of your system prevent some bad changes. It could happen that your AntiVirus is not working probably on the new OS(Some AntiVirus Software has problems with upgrading OS Installations)

Answer (score 0):

When updating from 8 to 8.1 the windows upgrade program will inform you which programs and files will be affected and how they are affected before they are affected(before it starts to install 8.1.).
As i remember when i did it third party programs are not reinstalled, but check as you go.
 If your anti-virus and firewall are windows defender and windows firewall they will be reinstalled or unaffected as part of the upgrade.
The age of the programs should not matter as the age difference between the upgrades is not long and anyway there is the compatibility program should you have any trouble.
All your files should be untouched.
Backing up your files is standard practice and always a wise move.